# How to count (Search) for specific text across multiple sheets via Google Docs?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-docs, google-docs-api

Currently I'm using the following formula to search and count the number of times a given text is used within a given cell:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!G3:G1151, "COMPLETE")
```

Any ideas how I can use the same formula against multiple sheets?

Something like the following:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1, Sheet2!G3:G1151, "COMPLETE")
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: add together one countif() for each sheet.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Craner would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!G3:G1151, "COMPLETE") + COUNTIF(Sheet2!G3:G1151, "COMPLETE") + ...`

Comment: Thanks @Scott Craner appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there are many sheets you want to look for, and to avoid having a to repeat the formula many times for each sheet, you can use a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) created in Google Apps Script instead. To achieve this, follow these steps:

- In your spreadsheet, select **Tools > Script editor** to open a script bound to your file.
- Copy this function in the script editor, and save the project:

```js
function COUNTMANYSHEETS(sheetNames, range, text) {
  sheetNames = sheetNames.split(',');
  var count = 0;
  sheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var values = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();
    values.forEach(function(row) {
      row.forEach(function(cell) {
        if (cell.indexOf(text) !== -1) count++;
      });
    });
  });
  return count;
};
```

- Now, if you go back to your spreadsheet, you can use this function just as you would do with any other function. You just have to provide a string with all the sheet names, separated by a separator specified in the code (in this sample, a comma), another one with the range you want to look for, and the text you want to look for, as you can see here, for example:

`=COUNTMANYSHEETS("Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3", "G3:G1151", "COMPLETE")`

#### Notes:

- It's important that you provide the sheet names separated by the separator specified in `sheetNames = sheetNames.split(',');`, and nothing else (not empty spaces after the comma, etc.).
- It's important that you provide the range in quotes (`"G3:G1151"`). Otherwise, the function will interpret this as an array of values corresponding to the specified range, and you won't be able to look for the values in other sheets.
- In this sample, the code looks for the string `COMPLETE`, and is case-sensitive. To make it case-insensitive, you could use [toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) or [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- If you wanted to look for all sheets in the spreadsheet, you could modify your function so that it only accepts the `range` and the `text` as parameters, and get all sheets via `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();`.

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)